# get coordinates event map openlayers 4.6.5 ~ 5

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I try to get the coordinates of a click on a openlayers map. My code is as follows:

```
const localmap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });

  function getPosition(event){
    console.log(localmap.getEventCoordinate(event));
}

  localmap.on('click', getPosition(event));
```

But the only thing I get this way is an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changedTouches' of undefined
```

I tried with adding the listener as

```
localmap.on('click', getPosition);
```

It displays an array on each click but it's filles with Nan values.

I tried seraching doc and all but it's either too old or writing the function directly in the listener, which I don't want cause I want to be able to remove it

Anybody has a clue to get those coordinates in ol 4.6.5 ~ 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out it just works with `event.coordinate`, displaying coordinates in the SRC defined in the layer

Comment: When i assign projection under view as EPSG:2326 and do event.coordinate does it give me EPSG:3857 or EPSG2326 ?

Comment: when you use the function, it returns in EPSG:3857 but you can convert them with ol.proj.transform(), see the answer from capnam. You can also look https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapBrowserEvent-MapBrowserEvent.html#coordinate but it's not really indicating anything sadly :/

Answer (score 12):

This code will work. Note that coordinates you will get are in `EPSG:3857` projection use `ol.proj.transform()` to convert them in to `EPSG:4326` projection. To know more about projections visit https://lyzidiamond.com/posts/4326-vs-3857. You must read this if you are going to work on openlayers frequently.

```
const localmap = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
});

localmap.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.coordinate);

    // convert coordinate to EPSG-4326
    console.log(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
});
```

Comment: The projection can be defined in the map without adding a layer so it would be weird to mandatory add a layer to get the coordinates

Comment: @Clement Correct. Agreed !